# Deep link to specific HomeKit accessory

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, homekit

My app displays a list of HomeKit accessory devices. I want to let users view the device in the iOS Home app for detailed configuration.

I'm able to deep link into the Home app like this:

```
let homeUrl = URL(string: "com.apple.Home://launch")
UIApplication.shared.open(homeUrl)
```

Is there a way to provide a URL to route into a specific device? I haven't found anything from Apple's docs related to HomeKit deep links. I've tried providing the device UUID in the URL, but I'm not sure how to formulate it correctly.